# Gomoku, is it possible to not be able to make a legal move?

Tags: gomoku

On a 11 across 12 down Gomoku board with the following conditions:

1. A player must make a move within 3 spaces of an opponent's piece.
2. **If a player can't make a move that player loses.**

Is it possible to force the above, given the conditions?

Comment: I have never heard of this rule, and an 11x12 board is a non-standard size. Do you have a reference for this rule?

Comment: This sounds like a theoretical research question in [m,n,k-games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M,n,k-game). In which case, I'm not sure you will find a very satisfactory answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for such a condition to happen, though I'm not sure what you mean by "force." It is possible because it is possible to create a board-state in which neither player has won the game, but the entire board is filled. A simple example of such a state is the following: imagine a filled 11x12 which follows the pattern:

```
WWBBWWBBWWBB

BBWWBBWWBBWW

WWBBWWBBWWBB

BBWWBBWWBBWW
```

Obviously, neither player has won the game, and since white and black each have an equal number of stones on the board, it is not impossible to reach such a board state. I have therefore shown that it is possible to reach a board-state in which one player cannot make a legal move. You can also show this for non-full boards by applying the rule of three and three and the rule of four and four.